# OkHttpClient cannot cancel Call by tag

Tags: java, okhttp

I recently upgraded to [OkHttp3](http://square.github.io/okhttp/), and noticed that you could no longer cancel a Call by tag directly from the Client. This has to be handled by the application now.

Stated in the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-300-rc1) here:

> **Canceling batches of calls is now the application's responsibility.**
>   The API to cancel calls by tag has been removed and replaced with a
>   more general mechanism. The dispatcher now exposes all in-flight calls
>   via its runningCalls() and queuedCalls() methods. You can write code
>   that selects calls by tag, host, or whatever, and invokes
>   Call.cancel() on the ones that are no longer necessary.

I'm self-answering this post with my simple utility method to cancel a running or queued Call by tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the following utility class to cancel a running or queued `Call` by tag:

```
public class OkHttpUtils {
    public static void cancelCallWithTag(OkHttpClient client, String tag) {
        // A call may transition from queue -> running. Remove queued Calls first.
        for(Call call : client.dispatcher().queuedCalls()) {
            if(call.request().tag().equals(tag))
                call.cancel();
        }            
        for(Call call : client.dispatcher().runningCalls()) {
            if(call.request().tag().equals(tag))
                call.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

I created an example, with a test case here: https://gist.github.com/RyanRamchandar/64c5863838940ec67f03

Comment: is this thread safe? is there a possibility that a call switches between lists while you are cancelling the calls?

Comment: That's a good point. Perhaps appending both running and queued calls in a single list, and cancelling with a single loop would be better. I didn't do this initially because of the performance hit.

Comment: From one of the OkHttp devs: https://twitter.com/jessewilson/status/709260263271309312

Comment: makes more sense to me now that you switched the order of the loops.

Comment: Yea, a `Call` can move from queued to running so cancelling the queued list first makes sense.

Comment: How does one set the tag on the Call in the first place? Thanks!

Comment: if the Call is canceled in queuedCalls(by checking Call.isCanceled() after call.cancel()), then we don't need to loop through runningCalls. And also good to add break statement inside if statement of loops.

Comment: @jettimadhuChowdary no since the objective is to cancel all queued/running calls matching the tag.

Comment: @RyanR if we have the same tag for multiple requests we can use the same solution. But If we have unique tags then you can consider my statement,