# How to cancel a request with Okhttp3.2?

Tags: okhttp

Using okhttp2.0,can cancel a request by

```
okhttpclient.cancel(tag);
```

Using okhttp3.2,What can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OkHttpClient cannot cancel Call by tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35964663/okhttpclient-cannot-cancel-call-by-tag)