# Cancel all Retrofit requests at once?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I know that individual Retrofit requests can be cancelled at any time by simply calling `retrofitCall.cancel();`

But I need a way to cancel all ongoing requests at once. Is it possible? I haven't found anything like it in the documentation.

Comment: Internally they use ConnectionPool , internally Used by OkHttp3.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You have to keep reference to your shared OkHttpClient.

Than when you want to cancel all requests just call:

```
client.dispatcher().cancelAll()
```

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: Thanks you, you saved me a lot of times ^^

Comment: Check this. it may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35964663/okhttpclient-cannot-cancel-call-by-tag

Comment: cannot find dispatcher methods in Retrofit client

Comment: Not sure why my client ain't cancelling calls. I'm using `Dagger2` for sharing a single instance of `OkHttpClient`. I've verified it by using `client.toString()` and they're having same hash code (meaning, same instance, right?). However, when I call `client.dispatcher().cancelAll()` nothing happens. I verified `client.dispatcher().queuedCallsCount()` and `client.dispatcher().runningCallsCount()` and they're returning `0` unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using OkHttp API to cancel will causing `mCall.isCanceled()` return false.